# how to send an object when using the mutlipart annotation in android retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i am trying to send a user object in a multipart request in android retrofit

```
@Multipart
    @POST("drivers")
    Call<JSONObject> addANewUser(
            @Body User user,
            @Part("licenceFrontPicture") RequestBody licenceFrontPicture,
            @Part("licenceBackPicture") RequestBody licenceBackPicture,
            @Part("idCardFrontPicture") RequestBody idCardFrontPicture,
            @Part("idCardBackPicture") RequestBody idCardBackPicture
    );
```

but i cant use the body annotation in this case
so how to convert the user object to a type that i can send

Answer (score 1):

> If you're sending JSON with your multi upload then that should be
> another @Part, not a @Body.
>
> When you use @Multipart you are specifying that the body is a
> multipart request and so all that's available for contributing to that
> body is @Parts.

Look into using @PartMap

```
Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();

RequestBody userBody = RequestBody.create(
                okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), 
                userJsonString);


map.put("licenceFrontPicture", RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);

map.put("userJSON", userBody);
```

=== Call Endpoint

```
@Multipart
@POST("drivers")
Call<Response> uploadMultiPart(@Path("id") int userId, @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```